# How to remove Windows 7 (loader) without losing data?

Tags: boot, grub2, bootloader, reboot

I've installed Ubuntu 15.10 in my laptop after removing Windows 7. Even after removing Windows 7 completely during Ubuntu installation I always get an option of Windows 7(loader) & other Ubuntu boot options. When I click on this Windows 7(loader) option I always get Windows 7 repair screen.
I want to completely remove this windows 7 loader from my hard disk without losing any data.
Please Help. 
Windows 7 (loader) option
[image: screenshot]
Screen I get after clicking on Windows 7(loader)
[image: screenshot]

Comment: In Ubuntu, what does `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sd?` say?

Comment: Have you tried updating grub?

Answer (score 2):

You should edit the `/etc/default/grub` file and add the following line:

```
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true
```

Save it and run `sudo update-grub`, it will remove Windows from your GRUB menu list.

Comment: do i have to save grub file as a new file ?

Comment: No, you don't need to save a new file.